# how to get the server name from a http response

Tags: java, http, http-method

I want to know from which server a response comes.

With a HttpMethod I'm readig the HttpStatus, the Method-Name and other stuff. But how do I get to know the Response-Server?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

```
boolean checkR(HttpMethod method){
    if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("HTTP response was " + method.getStatusLine().toString());
        return false;
    } 
  }
```

I would like to return something like this: "HTTP response was " + method.getStatusLine().toString()) + "from Server " + `??? Server-name ??`;

Comment: Your code might be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is that you cannot, since remote server address is not part of the HTTP response headers.

It is part of your request headers though with the field name `HOST`.

These are some of the headers fields in HTTP response:

```
ETag
Content-Length
Expires
Last-Modified
Connection
X-Powered-By
Server
Pragma
Cache-Control
Date
Vary
Keep-Alive
Content-Type
Accept-Ranges
```

[**`See this link for complete list`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses)